# azure blob storage logging / analytics gui tool?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm wondering if there is a good tool out there for viewing Azure blob storage logging results.

It's very nice what Azure's dash panel shows you already for total number of requests (in the last 6 hours, successful requests, and so forth), but I assume the logging (which comes at a price) allows greater detail, like how many times a particular blob has been requested in the last 6 hours.

I realize this works somehow by logging the results to a blob (in a root container $logs), but I would like to know if there are any nice GUI tools (3rd party or otherwise) for viewing this analytics data?

UPDATE: Thanks guys. I tried Cloud Storage Studio (2), and while it looked like it had nice graphs and all, the graphs didn't seem to show anything useful, or not at least for any areas I am interested in. For instance: "Container Count" is one of the areas. Do I really need analytics to count the number of containers I have? "Object Count". "Data Capacity" are two others, that I am not sure how that does anything beyond a very broad overview, such as you can already get on the dash panel. I want to see if it is possible to track a specific blob's usage. When you click the option to turn on such logging in the dash, it seemed to say you could do such things as track one blob's usage statistics. But maybe I am missing something with Cloud Storage Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cloud Storage Studio 2](http://www.cerebrata.com/products/cloudstoragestudio/Details.aspx?t1=0&t2=0) allows you to view the storage analytics:

> Cloud Storage Studio 2 allows you to configure your storage account to
>   capture storage analytics data using which you can find out the
>   storage account usage at a granular level. It also offers you the
>   capability to view the raw data as well as it has some pre-canned
>   reports to view the storage analytics data in graphical format. You
>   can download this reports data in CSV format for further analysis as
>   well as the capability to export the charts.

Comment: Cloud Storage Studio 2 allows you to view raw data stored in "$logs" blob container however it does not has the feature you're looking for. You would need to download the data, and the parse it manually to find how many times a blob has been accessed.

Answer (score 2):

There's also a Windows 8 Store App for Windows Azure Storage Analytics called [Azure Storage Monitor](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-US/app/azure-storage-monitor/e9292e05-c469-403d-a787-63645b861593).

> [Azure Storage Monitor](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-US/app/azure-storage-monitor/e9292e05-c469-403d-a787-63645b861593) provides a convenient way to access and visualize Windows Azure
>   Storage Analytics data. The graphs provide rich data insights into
>   your blob, table, and queue traffic. Prefer Excel pivot charts
>   instead? No problem. Easily export the data into an Excel spreadsheet
>   which automatically includes the raw data, pivot tables, and charts.